# Spring security: Restricting form interactivity using roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a form that allows users to interact with it depending on what role they have been assigned. For example my application has the role `role_user`, this role only allows users to view the form contents(not edit the form or submit it) and the role `role_admin` who can view/edit/submit the form.

The backend(service layer) was pretty straight forward to code for with these restrictions I use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('role_admin')")` on any service classes/methods which would result in changes being saved for my form. For example my method which saves the form on submit only allows `role_admin` users to execute this.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('role_admin')")
public void saveForm(MyForm myform){
//Save form here
}
```

On the front end(jsp,jstl and spring forms) i set a variables to determine who is logged in. For example the below sets `isUser` to `true` if the user is `role_user` otherwise `false`.

```
  <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" var="isUser" />
  <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" var="isAdmin" />
```

Then i apply  the userClass to my form if isUser is true, otherwise the adminClass of isAdmin is true(e.g. see below).

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test='${isAdmin}'>
       <c:set var="roleClass"    value="adminClass"/>
 </c:when>
  <c:when test='${isUser}'>
       <c:set var="roleClass"    value="userClass"/>
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
       <c:set var="roleClass" value="userClass"/>  
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<form:form class="${roleClass}">
```

I then use css to apply styling that is relevant for each role and use javascript to disable all form fields if the class "userClass" has been set(for `role_users` who shouldn't be able to edit anything).

This is my current solution and have found that as i add more roles with different restrictions (e.g. only disable specific form fields for some new roles) it becomes more cumbersome to maintain. Is their any better/recommended way of applying these restrictions on the front end form?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Spring Security Access Control Lists (ACL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) for this.

With this you can have permissions (View, Add, Edit, Delete)  for each role (ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN).

And in your code you just have to check whether a ROLE has the Particular Permission.

This way your application will not be ROLE dependent.

This Framework is very flexible and allows you to specify at a lower level what Object can be manipulated by a User or Role which has a permission.

You can see the [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/configure-domain-object)